# How do I manipulate this equation : $A(x^2+x)-B(x^2-x) = 4x^2-10x$ so i can solve for A and B?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given this polynomial equation $$A(x^2+x)-B(x^2-x) = 4x^2-10x$$ and I was given a clue in order to solve A and B, it is best to convert from the original equation to this :$$(A-B)x^2+(A+B)x = 4x^2-10x.$$

In general, can you show me how to convert $A(x^2+x)-B(x^2-x) = 4x^2-10x$ to $(A-B)x^2+(A+B)x = 4x^2-10x$?

Are there some kind of manipulations that I need to know?

Thank you every much!

Comment: So you're asking how to convert
$$
A(x^2 + x) - B(x^2 -x ) = 4x^2 -10x
$$
into
$$
(A-B)x^2 + (A+B)x = 4x^2 -10x
$$
? Answer: By opening the parentheses and juggling the terms around, it's not particularly difficult...

Comment: Yea that is my question @MattiP. excuse me sir can you please help me out

Comment: Opening parenthesis gives $Ax^2+Ax-Bx^2-(-1)Bx=4x^2-10x.$ Now put together terms with $x^2$ and together the terms with $x.$ This gives what @Matti P wrote.

Comment: First time someone referred to me as a mathematician. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A(x^2+x)-B(x^2-x) = 4x^2-10x$$

Open the brackets. It can be written as: $$Ax^2+Ax-B x^2-B(-x)=4x^2-10x$$
Or,$$Ax^2+Ax-B x^2+Bx=4x^2-10x.$$
Take $x^2$ common from $Ax^2$ and $Bx^2$ and $x$ common from $Ax$ and $Bx.$

$$(A-B)x^2+(A+B)x=4x^2-10x$$

Now compare both sides:

Equate terms having $x^2$ and those having x. 
you get:$$A-B=4$$ AND $$A+B=-10.$$
Solve simultaneously.

Comment: yes i have already got this answer since i was given the clue, but how do i algebraically convert this $A(x^2+x)-B(x^2-x) = 4x^2-10x$ to $(A-B)x^2+(A+B)x = 4x^2-10x$ and also thank you for answering!

Comment: edited, have a look

Comment: can stack exchange give this guy a medal?? Thank you so much from Australia!<3

Comment: you got it clear now?

Comment: yes sir! <3 Thank you again!

Comment: My pleasure; by the way, i am a student .. : )

Answer (score 4):

Take common factor $x^2$ and $x$ from both expressions. You'll be left with a polynomial of order two, and then you can solve for $A$ and $B$ by equating the resulting coefficients to $4$ and $-10$ respectively.

Answer (score 2):

So we are staring with 
$$
A(x^2 + x) - B(x^2 -x )
$$
Open the brackets, and the expressions becomes
$$
Ax^2 + Ax - Bx^2 + Bx
$$
For the context of the problem, we want to group the $x$'s and $x^2$ together, like so:
$$
Ax^2 - Bx^2 + Ax + Bx
$$
And now factoring the terms together, we get
$$
(A-B)x^2 + (A+B) x
$$
Any questions?

Comment: No more sir! This explained it all! Thank you prof Matti from Australia!